# AWS EKS Master Cluster Security Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I'm a bit confused about Security group for EKS Master Cluster on AWS.

As I understand it, there is no egress traffic allowed at all,
and as ingress it has to be to 443 as source from Worked-Nodes security group.

If I'am wrong please correct me

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS already provided the [EKS recommended security group settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/sec-group-reqs.htm)

For ingress rule, you are right, only 443 required for all worker node's security group.

For egress rule, you have to allow at least 10250 or 1025-65535 with worker node's security group for control plane to access worker node. But I think it should be fine to leave 0-65535 0.0.0.0/0 by default.